# How to get automatic adjustment of environment names?

Tags: environments, texstudio

On one of my computers, when I start a new environment with Ctrl+E (or edit the name of a different environment), if I start typing something inside the `\begin{...}` it automatically gets copied to the matching `\end{...}`.

On my other computer, this doesn't happen, so I must tediously copy the environment name from the `\begin` to the `\end`. What TexStudio setting controls this?

I am using TexStudio 2.10.2.

Comment: Do you use on both computers the same version of TeXStudio? Same OS on both computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to TexStudio 2.10.4 and this seems to have resolved the problem. Perhaps it was a bug in version 2.10.2.